# Replacing Data in Table for SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, replace

I've looked at a few different suggestions, but for some reason none of the following solutions have been able to work/have still duplicated data within the table.

"Category" would be the unique value for this SQLite table. Value to be altered is "spending_limit".

So far I've tried:

```
public void writeToSpendingLimits(int sequence, double amount){
    String sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO spending_limits(category, spending_limit) "
    + "VALUES(" + sequence + ", " +  amount + ");";           
    connection.executeSQL(sql);
}
```

.

```
public void writeToSpendingLimits(int sequence, double amount){           
        String sql = "INSERT INTO spending_limits (category, spending_limit) "
            + "VALUES(" + sequence + ", " + amount + ") "
            + "ON CONFLICT(category)"
            + "DO UPDATE SET spending_limit = " + amount + ";";
    connection.executeSQL(sql);
```

.

```
public void writeToSpendingLimits(int sequence, double amount){            
    String sql = "INSERT INTO spending_limits (category, spending_limit) "
            + "VALUES (coalesce((select category from spending_limits where category = " + amount + "),"
            + "(select max(category) from spending_limits) + 1), " + amount + ");";
    connection.executeSQL(sql);
```

.

```
public void writeToSpendingLimits(int sequence, double amount){              
    String sql = "UPDATE spending_limits " 
            + "SET category = " + sequence + ", " + "spending_limit = " + amount + " "
            + "WHERE spending_limit = " + sequence + ";\n"
            + "INSERT INTO spending_limits(category, spending_limit) "
            + "SELECT " + sequence + ", " + amount + " "
            + "WHERE (Select Changes() = 0)";
    connection.executeSQL(sql);
```

Comment: What's your table schema? What do you mean by not working?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want a single spending limit per category, then you could make the category a **UNIQUE** column. Then a duplicated category would result in a conflict and the conflict actions, such as **`OR REPLACE`**, would be undertaken.

e.g. consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS spending_limits;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spending_limits (category INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL, spending_limit REAL);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO spending_limits (category, spending_limit) VALUES(1,10.23);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO spending_limits (category, spending_limit) VALUES(2,10.23);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO spending_limits (category, spending_limit) VALUES(3,10.23);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO spending_limits (category, spending_limit) VALUES(4,10.23);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO spending_limits (category, spending_limit) VALUES(5,10.23);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO spending_limits (category, spending_limit) VALUES('Animal',10.23);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO spending_limits (category, spending_limit) VALUES('Vegetable',10.23);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO spending_limits (category, spending_limit) VALUES('Mineral',10.23);
SELECT *,rowid AS rid FROM spending_limits;
```

**`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO spending_limits (category, spending_limit) VALUES(1,11.23);`**

**`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO spending_limits (category, spending_limit) VALUES('Animal',11.23);`**

```
SELECT *,rowid AS rid FROM spending_limits;
```

This will :-

- DROP the **spending_limits** table if it exists (simplifies testing)
- CREATE the **spending_limits** table, noting that the category column has the **UNIQUE** attribute.
- INSERT 8 rows to the **spending_limits** table (mixed category types for demonstration purposes)
- SELECT all rows and output them
- INSERT 2 duplicate rows, according to category, but with an adjusted amount.

  - i.e.  the statement inserts a new row or replaces an existing row dependant upon whether or not the category already existed.
- SELECT all rows and output them.

The results being :-

After the initial insertion of the 8 rows :-

[image]

After the inserting (replace) of the 2 rows that have existing categories :-

[image]

- **Note** The **rowid** column is also updated (this could therefore be a candidate for being a WITHOUT ROWID table)